# Inner join on inner join?

Tags: sql, db2

```
      **TableFruits**                        **TableNames**
   RecId    RId      FruitId       Price         RId  FruitId       Name
     1      A1        Null           3$           A1      1        Mango
     2      A2         2             4$           A2      2       Tomato
```

Since there is Null under FruitId in TableFruits I want to fetch it from TableNames like

```
Select a.RecId,a.RId,b.FruitId from TableFruits a INNER JOIN TableNames b on a.RId=b.RId
```

1. How do I apply a join in this SQL statement to include FruitNames from Table 2 (I cannot change the order of tables)

Comment: I want something like   RecId,RId,FruitId,Names in my result.

Comment: When a `RID` exists in one table, does it also exist in the other table, too? Or there are mismatches?

Comment: Then you need an outer join. `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL`, depending on which side the mismatches can occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.RecId
     , a.RId
     , COALESCE(a.FruitId, b.FruitId) AS FruitId
     , b.Name
FROM TableFruits a 
  JOIN TableNames b 
    ON b.RId = a.RId  ;
```

Since you can have mismatches in `RId`, you need an outer join. `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL`, depending on which side the mismatches can occur.

MySQL does not have `FULL JOIN`, so you can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.RecId
     , a.RId
     , COALESCE(a.FruitId, b.FruitId) AS FruitId
     , b.Name
FROM TableFruits a 
  LEFT JOIN TableNames b 
    ON b.RId = a.RId 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL
     , NULL
     , b.FruitId
     , b.Name
FROM TableFruits a 
  RIGHT JOIN TableNames b 
    ON b.RId = a.RId 
WHERE a.RId IS NULL  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.RecId,a.RId,a.FruitId, b.Name
from TableFruits a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableNames b on a.RId=b.RId
```

Comment: Can you do this by applying an inner join on my query ? This is just an example.

Comment: @DamienJoe: See ypercube's answer.